# any reason to use printf over format or vice versa in java

Tags: java, format, printf

Im learning formatting in Java and have been using printf and format methods.
To me these seem to behave exactly the same.

Is there any reason why I should use one over the other ?

Is one considered newer and/or a better one to use as standard and if so why?

Comment: they behave the same; use whichever more convenient in each circumstance.

Answer (score 4):

The situations in which you use them can be different; if you want to print a text it's normally easier to use `printf()`. If you want to do something else with the String (e.g. put it into a graphical element or a logger) then you'll use `String.format()`.

Comment: i guess because im a beginner I havent started to see situations where I would use one over the other but will do in the future -  i aware to look out for it now though, thanks

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. But trust me, both alternatives can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 3):

The `PrintStream#printf(...)` methods actually delegate to the `PrintStream#format(...)` methods.  So no, there should be no difference.

Edit:
If you are talking about `String.format(...)`, this performs the formatting in exactly the same manner; the difference is that it returns the formatted `String` instead of writing it to the stream.